# Can't edit records in table linked to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I'm having problems with editing records via MS Access in a table linked to Sharepoint site ever since i changed the properties of a couple of fields in different tables. Now when I try to edit or enter new record I get an error message "Invalid argument".

I was changing the properties of tables via .accdw file and I have full permission to the Sharepoint site so it's not because of the limited access.

I also tired editing the record directy in Sharepoint but i got an error message saying "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904". 
I did some research and I found out this could be caused by a corrupt index or that content database for the SharePoint site is full. I tried removing all the indexes but I couldn't because "server requires the search fields to the integrity of the data indexed" (I got this error when i tried removing indexes). I can't get the info about the content database size since I'm not the system administrator (he's currently on holiday)

Does anyone know if corrupt indexes are actually the cause of this? If so, how do I fix them?
If not, is there a way I can sole this issue or do I have to wait for the system administrator to come back?

I am using Access 2010, 32 bit.

Comment: Hopefully, [you didn't modify the SQL tables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057), or did you?

Comment: No, I changed only the tables that I created